# Configuration Profile with MDM Payload not getting installed using IPCU

Tags: ios, configuration, identity, mdm, payload

Does anybody know how to set the "Identity" of the Mobile Device Management (MDM) payload of a Configuration Profile from iPhone Configuration Utility (iPCU)?

I get many certificates from Apple.com(aps_ssl_production and ios_distribution ),but I don't known how to install the MDM Payload.

Comment: I generated push certificate for MDM. Its got a valid subject/topic. When viewed in keychain store it says "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority". There's also no private key associated with it. Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in a p12 file/certificate as a 'Credential' in iPCU and pick this from the list in the MDM view. You do not have to use SCEP to do this.

Comment: Thanck you for your advice.Is any p12 file useful?

Comment: Yes. Unless you wish to sign your MDM messages from the device. If you do, then you will need to ensure that the p12 contains a certificate and the associated key.

Comment: How to get the p12 associated certificate and key?

Answer (score 2):

use SCEP Settings to provide instructions for the device to obtain the certificate using SCEP as mentioned in [FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility_Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility/Introduction/Introduction.html)

So first do configure SCEP using IPCU and then configure Mobile Device Management and then create the config profile and try to install that config in iOS device.

While configuring make sure there should no invalid entry for any field and no red icon for any field.

**Edit:**
For few no of devices no need to use SCEP. You can go through this [link](http://www.abstractec.co.uk/wordpress/ios-mdm-guide/) for more detail.
[image]